# WP Supersized & Easy Fancybox Conflict

Tags: jquery

I am using WP Supersized and Easy Fancybox Wordpress plugins. Everything is works fine till the point I am not clicking the link to open a fancybox. Image is opening perfectly just having some issues with the position. Its shifting towards the left on opening up.

Here is the link to my demo page where I am using fancybox : http://martinushoeve.dig-id.be/?page_id=5

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted out the answer for this.

Here is the culprit the culprit: the jquery.animate-enhanced.js file that had been added since version 3.1.2 is creating the issue.

Comment out this line :

```
wp_register_script('jquery_animate_enhanced', content_url().'/plugins/wp-supersized/js/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js',array('jquery'),self::supersized_jquery_animate_enhanced_version)
```

probably on line 55 in this file: 
wp-content/plugins/wp-supersized/includes/WPSupersized.php

This is working for me now.